# IE11 multiple background image issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm working on a building coloring application. As I'm having issues with the responsiveness in IE with SVG layers, I'm using multiple PNG backgrounds for displaying different part of the building in different colors according to the user's choice. I'm adding multiple background images dynamically with javascript :

```
var building_part_bg = new Array();
    var wall_bg    = '';
    var roof_bg    = '';
    var eave_bg    = '';
    var gable_bg   = '';
    var corners_bg = '';
    var frames_bg  = '';
    var building_bg     = 'url(assets/images/1_part_eave_background.png)';

    function setColor(id, building_part)
    {
        id = id.replace(' ', '_');

        switch (building_part) {
            case 'wall':
                wall_bg = 'url(assets/images/eave_1/wall_'+id+'.png), ';
            break;
            case 'roof':
                roof_bg = 'url(assets/images/eave_1/roof_'+id+'.png), ';
            break;
            case 'eave':
                eave_bg = 'url(assets/images/eave_1/eave_'+id+'.png), ';
            break;
            case 'gable':
                gable_bg = 'url(assets/images/eave_1/gable_'+id+'.png), ';
            break;
            case 'corners':
                corners_bg = 'url(assets/images/eave_1/corners_'+id+'.png), ';
            break;
            case 'frames':
                frames_bg = 'url(assets/images/eave_1/frames_'+id+'.png), ';
            break;
        }

        //var all_layers = wall_bg + roof_bg + eave_bg + gable_bg + corners_bg + frames_bg + building_bg;
        var all_layers = frames_bg + corners_bg + gable_bg + eave_bg + roof_bg + wall_bg + building_bg;

        building_part_bg.push('url(assets/images/eave_1/'+building_part+'_'+id+'.png), ');
        for (i=0; i<building_part_bg.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById('building_area').style.backgroundImage = all_layers;
        }
        console.log(all_layers);
        all_layers = '';
    }
```

Here's the PHP/HTML (I won't place neither all the PHP code nor the HTML output because of the vast amount of colors for each building part) :

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <div class="building_area_eave_1" id="building_area">
                    <img class="svg_layers" src="<?php echo HTTP_IMAGES_PATH;?>/building_transparent.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
       <div id="tabbed">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="myTab">
                        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#show_walls">Wall Panel</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#show_roof">Roof Panel</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#show_eave">Eave Trim</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#show_gable">Gable Trim</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#show_corners">Corner Trim</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#show_frames">Framed Opening Trim</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#show_rollup">Rollup Door</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="show_walls">
                            <?php
                            $color_group = array(1=> 'SIGNATURE&#174; 200', 'VALSPAR', 'SIGNATURE&#174; 300');
                            if( isset($colors) && sizeof($colors) > 0 )
                            {
                                for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) {
                                    echo '<br /><small>'.$color_group[$i].'</small><br />';
                                    foreach ($colors as $key => $value)
                                    {
                                        if ($i == $value['color_category']) {
                                            switch ($value['color_name']) {
                                                case "Polar White":
                                                    $button_width = 12;
                                                break;
                                                default:
                                                    $button_width = 3;
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                            <div class="col-sm-<?php echo $button_width; ?> nopadding">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="setColor('<?php echo $value['color_name']; ?>', 'wall')" style="background-color:#<?php echo $value['color_code'] ;?>; color:#ffffff;"><?php echo $value['color_name']; ?></button>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    }
                                    echo '<div style="clear:both"></div><br />';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
              </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS :

```
#building_area {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
    position: relative;
}

.svg_layers {
    opacity:0;
}

.building_area_eave_1{
    background: url("../images/1_part_eave_background.png") no-repeat;
}
```

This works fine in FF, Google Chrome, Safari but not in IE (I have tested in version 11.0.9600.17239). I have put a commented row in my JS (var all_layers...) because it seems that's the part where IE 'looses control'. When I select the colors from left-to-right order, it works fine in IE too, but when selecting colors in random order, or from right to left, IE doesn't load the selected background image. It took me 2 days to realize this behaviour and I'm more than confused WHY it is happening... I couldn't find any other logic in IE, except sometimes it loads the previously selected backgrounds (all at once) when I click again some previously loaded building part. To see and try online what am I talking about, please check out the application [demo](http://flexymanagement.com/buck_steel/steel_building/eave1).

Any suggestion and help is highly appreciated.

Comment: i tested your demo link on windows 7 (64-bit) IE11 `version 11.0.9600.18097` and i see it working when i select colors in a random order or in a non-random order

Comment: @JonathanMarzullo wow that's good news. Thanks for the feedback. Maybe it's my browser/OS (Windows 7 32bit)? Anyway, I hope I'll get feedback from others who may test it...